# C++ symbol referencing error

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, exception

I've been trying to find what the problem is to this following code part. I've written a custom exception class where I have a base class for stack errors, and then some classes deriving from it one of them called `stack_full_error`.
I have some problem compiling it though, I get the following error.

```
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
stack_error::~stack_error()         /var/tmp//ccFwZ5Kd.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to a.out
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It says something about the destructor, and I have been trying some things to fix it, with no success. Anyway I hope someone can tell me what the problem is.

```
class stack_error : public exception
{
public:
   stack_error(string const& m) throw()
      : exception(), msg(m) {};
   virtual ~stack_error() throw() =0;
   virtual const char* what() const throw()
   {
      return msg.c_str();
   }

private:
   string msg;
};

class stack_full_error : public stack_error
{
public:
   stack_full_error() throw()
      : stack_error("Exception: stack full") {};
   ~stack_full_error() throw() {};
};
```

And here where I call the exception for this first time

```
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(T i)
{   
   if(is_full())
      throw stack_full_error();

   this->first = new Node<T>(this->first, i);
   amount++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure virtual or not, `stack_error` must *define* its destructor because it is implicitly called from `stack_full_error` destructor. You should add :

```
stack_error::~stack_error() {}
```

in an implementation file.

Comment: sweet solved the problem, didn't knew you had to define destructor although it's made pure virtual.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have an abstract destructor. You need to define it in `stack_error`. (see the correction below)

Did you mean to make in *virtual*?

Unlike other virtual functions, virtual destructors are not overriding each other. The destructors of all the base classes will be executed sequentially (starting from the most derived class destructor). Each class musty have a destructor; even if you don't define a destructor, it's created implicitly.

**Correction:**
You can make the destructor abstract, but need to define its body anyway. Like that:

```
virtual ~stack_error() = 0 {};
```

if this your compiler the latest C++0x features. Otherwise you have to define the body outside:

```
class stack_error
{
    ...
    virtual ~stack_error() = 0;
    ...
};
stack_error::~stack_error() {}
```

Abstract (`=0`) means that it needs to be defines in the derived classes; nevertheless you have to define the destructor's body.

Comment: pure virtual functions may not have an inline definition, and I'm not sure C++0x changes that

Comment: @icecrime: well, AFAIK at C++0x this syntactic sugar is allowed. I checked with my current compiler, it still doesn't allow this :-(.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure destructors can (should?) be abstract. [Destructors should be virtual](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.7) but I seem to remember having issues when they where abstract.

Comment: Destructors *can* be pure virtual, but must have an implementation even if they are. You could do this to force the class to be abstract when it doesn't have any other pure virtual functions, although I can't think of a reason for wanting to do that.